# Run one Magento 2 instance with Wildcard Subdomains

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, zend-framework

Is it possible to run one instance of Magento 2 with wildcard Subdomains?

For example, 
I want to run

> **geen**.myshop.com

or

> **blue**.myshop.com

It should always be called the same shop. 
The subdomain keyword, I would like to query the database and insert text on the homepage.

Comment: You'd probably need to configure them as different stores in Magento, but yes

Comment: I would like to avoid this.